# Backup and restore ENTIRE Azure SQL server (not individual DBs)

Tags: sql, azure, backup, azure-sql-database

We use Azure as infrastructure for our app and its SQL DBs.

Currently Azure provides automatic backups for all tiers (Basic to Premium), but these settings are individual per DB.

How can I set backup for the entire server, with all DBs inside?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, backups are configured on database level. When you backup all of your databases, the database server is considered backed up. More information on the topic: [Azure SQL Database Backup and Restore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj650016.aspx)